# Autohotkey (AHK) Multiple Gui Submit

Tags: windows, user-interface, submit, autohotkey

Having read all of the posts I could find, I'm still stuck - really hoping for some help or guidance here.

I have a AHK script to help automate a work task that I have to do quite often. The below code works for the first script/GUI but when trying to do the second hotkey, the GUI pops up but won't let me hit submit.

```
Gui, Add, MonthCal, vADayPick
Gui, Add, DateTime, vATime, hh:mm tt
Gui, Add, Button, Default, ASubmit

Gui, 2:Add, MonthCal, vBDayPick
Gui, 2:Add, DateTime, vBTime, hh:mm tt
Gui, 2:Add, Button, Default, BSubmit

Gui, 3:Add, MonthCal, vCDayPick
Gui, 3:Add, DateTime, vCTime, hh:mm tt
Gui, 3:Add, Button, Default, CSubmit


^+i::
Gui, Show
return

ButtonASubmit:
Gui, Submit
FormatTime, ADayPick, %ADayPick%, dddd MMMM d, yyyy
FormatTime, ATimePick, %ATime%, h:mm tt

SendInput First GUI output - %ADayPick%        %ATimePick%

return

^+o::
Gui, 2:Show
return

ButtonBSubmit:
Gui, 2:Submit
FormatTime, BDayPick, %BDayPick%, dddd MMMM d, yyyy
FormatTime, BTimePick, %BTime%, h:mm tt


Gui, 3:Show
return

ButtonCSubmit:
Gui, 3:Submit
FormatTime, CDayPick, %CDayPick%, dddd MMMM d, yyyy
FormatTime, CTimePick, %CTime%, h:mm tt

SendInput Second GUI output - %BDayPick%        %BTimePick%
SendInput Third GUI output - %CDayPick%         %CTimePick%

return
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I've read through multiple examples and am still coming up short.

Comment: You are aware that in your label `ButtonBSubmit`, there is no `Send` command, aren't you? If your script were working properly, the only thing which will happen after a click on `BSubmit`, is the pop-up of `Gui:3`.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearer programming style to provide your `Gui, add ...`-statements with custom labels.
If I were you, I'd replace

`Gui, Add, Button, Default, ASubmit`

with

`Gui, Add, Button, Default gButtonASubmit, ASubmit`

(same for B and C).

`g` stands for `GoTo`. This way, you assure that the label which is called from the button exists. After making this little adjustment your code will work. I cannot explain exactly why, though. It seems, ahk was somehow able to connect button A with `ButtonASubmit`, which does not make any sense to me. Least, ahk was **not** able to connect button B to `ButtonBSubmit`.